# Check wire continuity without microcontroller

Tags: wire

Basically I need to create 2 devices that are not connected to each other. One should be connected to one end of the wire and the second one to the other end. If it detects that it’s the same wire, it should turn on a buzzer.

What I already tried: making a simple transistor-buzzer circuit which would turn the transistor on when it detects voltage from the wire (I connected the + of a battery to the wire), but quickly realised this won’t work.

What else can I try?

Also, I don’t want to use any microcontrollers, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at network testers, there are DIY circuits out there that can give you ideas to use.

Comment: So in the end (during detection) should the two devices be electrically connected together through the same wire?  Or should the first device be detecting that the other device is connected to a wire in close proximity but not electrically connected?

Comment: They should be connected trough the same wire, but what I’m trying to do is make the first device send a signal or something that can be detected by the second device, causing it to activate the buzzer.

Comment: What length is this wire? Is a connection to Earth or a chassis available?

Comment: Between how many wires do you want to distinguish or is there only one?

Comment: Just one wire, and there is no connection to earth available.

Answer (score 2):

A cable locator/tracer typically works with RF.
Inject some kind of signal onto the cable and detect it on the other end.

They almost always require an earth connection. So if all you have is 1 wire, you probably are not going to get this done.

Comment: At a reasonably high frequency, you can transmit a signal over one wire, without a ground.